# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'data' in GoogleColab

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, solver, google-colaboratory

**I had import and mount the data in ggdrive by this code**

```
    import pandas as pd
    from google.colab import drive

drive.mount('/content/gdrive', force_remount=True)
```

**And then i call back a def in this file**

```
from data.generator import DataGenerator
```

So i had a problem with this module name,it isn't name of a module ,it's a name of a file in direct folder. Hope someone can solve this problem for me

Comment: Could you provide an error message, and explain exactly what data.generator is? Is it the name of the class containing the code in the first code block?

Comment: Welcome to SO! The title of your question can be improved to reflect the actual problem you are facing (Unable to load a file from gdrive?). Please go through [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a question. It will help others to answer your question if you add more information like : your attempt, detailed error log's and exected outcome.

Answer (score 0):

You have to run the python script from the right folder. So before running the python script add a line like:
`%cd "/content/gdrive/MyDrive/Machine Learning/005 Handwriting Recognition/handwritten-text-recognition/src"`